# SharePoint 2010 -

Tags: system-master-page

I have created a sub site in sharepoint 2010, which looks better than the actual master page.

How can I turn a sub site into a master site/page?

Help please!!

Comment: Please be more specific with your question .

Answer (score 1):

Please check what master page you have used for you sub site . Apply the same to your Root site collection.

Navigate to your sub site , Click on Site Actions->Site Settings
Under Master page, check what master page has been applied .

Now go to the Root site collection and go to the site settings and apply the same master page as it was for the sub site.

Comment: Can you please add more details to this answer about how to do so?

Comment: Im quite new to sharepoint. Can you explain it in a little bit more detail? Thank you

Comment: Can you tell me which part you are struggling at the moment ?